# delete data from database using model in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am trying to delete data from my table employes by getting the id of the data and transferring it by using get route but i get the following  error

> ModelNotFoundException in Builder.php line 125: No query results for
>   model [App\employe].

her is my route

```
Route::get('/delete/{employe}', 'EmployeController@delete');
Route::post('/delete', 'EmployeController@handleDelete');
```

and i have model called employe to access my table

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class employe extends Model {

    protected $fillable = array('fname','lname','age','sex','phone','email','houseno','city','kebele','state','username','password','workposition','salary','bankaccount','bankname','contactid','employedate');


}
```

part of my  controller for deleting

```
    public function delete(employe $employe)
    {
    // Show delete confirmation page.
    return View('deleteemploye', compact('employe'));
    }

    public function handleDelete()
    {


    $employe = employe::findOrFail(Input::get('employe'));
    $employe->delete();

    return Redirect::action('EmployeController@index');

}
```

her is my view for deleting file

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')

    <div class="page-header">
        <h2>Delete {{$employe->fname}} Are you sure?</h2>
    </div>
    <form action="{{ action('EmployeController@handleDelete') }}" method="post" role="form">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="employe"  id="employe" value="{{ $employe->id }}" />
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Yes" />
        <a href="{{ action('EmployeController@index') }}" class="btn btn-default">No</a>
    </form>
@stop
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like laravel cant find the model with the primary key you are passing. Check the database and see if its there. If it is check the `deleted_at` field. If it has a date in it, it means it is already deleted. You can still find it by using `withTrashed()`

```
$employe = employe::withTrashed()->findOrFail(Input::get('employe'));
```

and if you have soft deleting enabled for this model, you can completely remove the given row by running

```
$employe = employe::withTrashed()->findOrFail(Input::get('employe'))->forceDelete();
```

Comment: the data is there,it is not deleted

Comment: do you have the deleted_at column, and if so, is it null?

Comment: i have updated_at column and it is the same time as created at but i don't have deleted_at column .